# Angular Material Form Input messed up

Tags: angular, angular-material

My Form boxes are messed up:
[image]

I copied the exact code from Material's site:

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill" floatLabel="always">
        <mat-label>Min Price</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="number" class="example-right-align" placeholder="0" name="minPrice" [(ngModel)]="userParams.minPrice">
        <span matTextPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
        <span matTextSuffix>.00</span>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" floatLabel="always">
        <mat-label>Max Price</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="number" class="example-right-align" placeholder="0" name="maxPrice" [(ngModel)]="userParams.maxPrice">
        <span matTextPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
        <span matTextSuffix>.00</span>
      </mat-form-field>
```

The example on the official website shows that it should look like this: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your matTextPrefix and matTextSuffix. Try this:

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill" floatLabel="always">
        <mat-label>Min Price</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="number" class="example-right-align" placeholder="0" name="minPrice" [(ngModel)]="userParams.minPrice">
        <span matPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
        <span matSuffix>.00</span>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" floatLabel="always">
        <mat-label>Max Price</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="number" class="example-right-align" placeholder="0" name="maxPrice" [(ngModel)]="userParams.maxPrice">
        <span matPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
        <span matSuffix>.00</span>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Here is a screenshot of where I got the code:
[image]

Comment: That did indeed work.  Its frustrating though because the documentation says the code is using matTextSuffix and there is no information about what the difference is between matTextSuffix and matSuffix.  If you have any more information please share!

Comment: Could you please share the documentation from where you copied the code because, in the official material doc, it is matSuffix and matPrefix over there?

Comment: I got it from here: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview